# Purpose of zeromq send high watermark

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq, jeromq, jzmq, czmq

The first time I skimmed the zeromq docs, I assumed that the sender high watermark was there to ensure that the sender did not get too far ahead of the receiver.  Now that I'm looking at it more carefully, it seems that this can't possibly be true, since the wire protocol doesn't have any concept of ACKs so the sender can't know whether the receiver is keeping up or is way behind.  After staring at jeromq code in the debugger for way too long, it seems that the watermark is actually a purely "within-same-process" mechanism to ensure that the application thread that's writing to the ZMQ socket does not get too far ahead of the background thread that's responsible for taking messages off the ZMQ socket and writing bytes into the OS's TCP socket.

It seems like a rather fringe thing to worry about, relative to how much attention it's given in the docs.  It doesn't even seem like a great way to control memory usage, because if you have a high water mark of 10, then 15 messages of 2kb each is not allowed, but 5 messages of 100 megs each is allowed, so things are still pretty un-predictable.

Am I understanding all this correctly or am I hopelessly confused.

Answer (score 1):

I think that another thing that says it's not to prevent a sender getting too far ahead of the receiver is that if one set the HWM to 0, that's taken as infinity not actually zero. For 0 to mean zero, it'd have to have some too-ing and fro-ing with the receiver to know whether the socket was actually empty throughout the whole connection.

I wish that 0 did mean zero, because then ZeroMQ could implement both Actor Model *and* Communicating Sequential Processes architectures. But it doesn't, so it can't.

**Possible Uses**

None the less, a potential useful aspect is related to the fact that ZeroMQ is Actor Model. Suppose one were sending messages, and it kind of mattered whether or not those messages got through. In the situation where the link has collapsed (something that ZeroMQ's heartbeat can tell you, pretty quickly), messages already sent are potentially lost forever. However, if the HWM is being used to throttle the rate of messages being sent by the application, then the number of lost messages when the link breaks is minimised.

Obviously with CSP - the perfect architecture so far as I'm concerned! - you lose no messages (because the acts of sending and receiving are an execution rendezvous; the send won't complete until the receive has also completed).

What I have done in the past is to queue up messages for transmission in the sending application, sending them as and when the socket / connection can ingest them. Having the outbound message queue in the sending application's control (instead of in ZeroMQ's control) means that sender state can potentially get ahead of the transfer of messages, but still recover easily from a network connection fault.

I have written systems where a `sender` has a choice of two pathways to send messages through - `prime` and `spare` - and if the link to `prime` has collapsed the `sender` continues to send to `spare` instead. Having queued the messages inside the application and not in the socket allows the `sender`'s state can get ahead of the actual transfer of messages, knowing that if a link goes down it's still got all the unsent outboud messages that have been generated in the meantime. These can then be directed at `spare` instead, without having to rewind the `sender`'s internal state (which could be really tricky) to the last known successful transfer.

Something like that, anyway.

"Why not send to both `prime` and `spare` anyway?" is a valid question. Well, sometimes things can be complicated...